# PsychoPy: Runtime error while logging a message ("TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'")

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, error-logging, psychopy

I get a syntax error in PsychoPy’s PTB logging code.
My code:

```
from psychopy import logging
log = logging.LogFile("WS_Dev.log", level = logging.DEBUG, filemode = "w")
logging.log(logging.DEBUG, "in getArguments()")
```

and the error message:

```
File "./myProject.py", line 119, in getArguments
    logging.log(logging.DEBUG, "in getArguments()")
  File "./myProject-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psychopy/logging.py", line 410, in log
    root.log(msg, level=level, t=t, obj=obj)
  File "./myProject-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psychopy/logging.py", line 282, in log
    if level < self.lowestTarget:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

While I could get into PsychoPy's source code and fix this myself, I don't want to modify public domain open-source software.
(1) Has anybody else seen this, or got a workaround?  I can't believe PsychoPy shipped with such a glaring bug.  Yet I see no mention of it in either the PsychoPy forum or stack overflow.
(2) How can I file a bug report against PsychoPy, other than posting this question in the PsychoPy forum?

macOS 12.2.1 (Monterey), 2017 MacBook Pro,
PsychoPy 2021.2.3,
psychtoolbox 3.0.18.2,
Python 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `logging.log`...

```
>>> from psychopy import logging
>>> help(logging.log)

Help on function log in module psychopy.logging:

log(msg, level, t=None, obj=None)
    Log a message

    usage::
        log(level, msg, t=t, obj=obj)

    Log the msg, at a  given level on the root logger
```

...it looks like the `usage::` documentation has the first two
parameters backwards. According to the function signature, you should
be calling:

```
logging.log("in getArguments()", logging.DEBUG)
```

And that seems to work without errors when I test it.

This seems like a good opportunity for making a documentation pull request against the project.

Comment: Good catch!  I don’t know how to do a pull request and submit the correction. Could you point me to appropriate instructions?

Comment: GitHub has some documentation on contributing to projects [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/contributing-to-projects), and for example [this post](https://jarv.is/notes/how-to-pull-request-fork-github/) is a quick summary of the pull request workflow. There are literally hundreds of others , both videos and documents, if you search for something like "how do I make a  pull request".

Comment: Thanks both of you. Most people probably use
`logging.debug("in getArguments()")` so the documentation error never got noticed.

Kim, very happy to help you with how to submit fixes in the future. For now I've pushed the docs but, in the meantime, the bug is fixed here:
https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/pull/4648/commits/e67800a45d315568c8cc9bf851a5a0c027b27ee7
and that will be in the updated docs when that fix gets pulled into the repo (later today I expect)